# Spring Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: spring, database, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, repository

I am trying to create a custom method for all my repositories and am getting this error. Thank you for your help!
DailyData:

```
package com.test.demo.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Daily_Data")
public class DailyData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Day")
    private int time;
    @Column(name = "Average_Energy_Value")
    private double dailyAvgEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Maximum_Energy_Value")
    private double dailyMaxEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Minimum_Energy_Value")
    private double dailyIdleEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "topics")
    private String topics;
}
```

HourlyData:

```
package com.test.demo.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "HourlyData")

public class HourlyData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Hour")
    private int time;
    @Column(name = "Average_Energy_Value")
    private double hourlyAvgEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Maximum_Energy_Value")
    private double hourlyMaxEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Idle_Energy_Value")
    private double hourlyIdleEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "topics")
    private String topics;
}
```

Weekly Data:

```
package com.test.demo.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Weekly_Data")
public class WeeklyData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Week")
    private int time;
    @Column(name = "Average_Energy_Value")
    private double weeklyAvgEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Maximum")
    private double weeklyMaxEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Weekly_Data")
    private double weeklyIdleEnergy_value;
    @Column(name = "Weekly_Data")
    private String topics;
}
```

RawData:

```
package com.test.demo.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="Raw_Data")
public class RawData {
    //same as in MqttDataModel
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
    //TODO:mqttID?
    //Same
    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    public double timestamp;

    //Same
    @Column(name = "energy_value")
    public double energy_value;
    //Same
    @Column(name="topics")
    public String topics;

    public String getTopics() {
        return topics;
    }

    public void setTopics(String topics) {
        this.topics = topics;
    }

    public double getEnergy_value() {
        return energy_value;
    }

    public void setEnergy_value(double energy_value) {
        this.energy_value = energy_value;
    }

    public double getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(double timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Generic Repository:

```
package com.test.demo.GenericRepo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T,Long extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    public List<T> findFromToTimestamp(T t, double beginTime, double endTime);
    public List<T> findByTime(T t, double time);
    public List<T> findByTopics(T t, List<String> topics);

}
```

GenericRepositoryImpl:

```
package com.test.demo.GenericRepo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


    public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, Long extends Serializable>
            extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long> implements GenericRepository<T, Long> {
        private EntityManager entityManager;
        public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
            super(domainClass, em);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public List<T> findFromToTimestamp(T t, double beginTime, double endTime) {
            return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM :t WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :begin AND :end").setParameter("t", t.getClass()).setParameter("begin", beginTime).setParameter("end", endTime).getResultList();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public List<T> findByTime(T t, double time) {
            return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM :t WHERE timestamp like :v").setParameter("t", t.getClass()).setParameter("v", time).getResultList();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public List<T> findByTopics(T t, List<String> topics) {
            return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM :t WHERE topics like :v").setParameter("t", t.getClass()).setParameter("v", topics.toString()).getResultList();
        }
    }
```

RawDataRepository:

```
package com.test.demo.Repositories;



import com.test.demo.Entities.RawData;
import com.test.demo.GenericRepo.GenericRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RawDataRepository extends GenericRepository<RawData, Long> {





}
```

Other repositories and services look the same
DailyDataService:

```
package com.test.demo.Services;

import com.test.demo.Repositories.DailyDataRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class DailyDataService {

    DailyDataRepository dailyDataRepository;


}
```

Application:

```
package com.test.demo;

import com.test.demo.GenericRepo.GenericRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.demo.Repositories",
      repositoryBaseClass = GenericRepositoryImpl.class)
public class TestApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
   }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>testdb2</name>
   <description>demo</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20220924</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.30</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <version>42.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Error
log:`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5] at com.test.demo.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]`

I checked everything again and again, bit I am really not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the full error log please?

Comment: I added the error log to the post. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you run with `--debug` and provide the full stacktrace. There must be more to it then this. One thing that worries me is that you are using Spring Boot 2.7.5 as the parent and Spring Boot 3.0.0 for dependencies, that will lead to a strange mix of dependencies, you can also remove the `hibernate` dependency as that already comes in from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. `lombok` and `junit` are added twice.

Comment: That's really strange, thank you for noticing! I changed the Spring version to 3.0.0 and now it does not recognize javax like in my other projects. I will change everything to jakarta and will tell you if that was the problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum ,  It was the version. I had another error, that has nothing to do with this one, but now everything is working. Thank you so much! I totally missed that it could be the Spring version. Can you post an answer to my question, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is that you are mixing different versions of Spring Boot. Version 3.0.0 and 2.7.5, this leads to a strange mix of dependencies. Your dependency management also defeats te purpose of the parent, which manages all the versions for you. You should remove the `version` tag from the dependencies you are using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>testdb2</name>
   <description>demo</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.json</groupId>
         <artifactId>json</artifactId>
         <version>20220924</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
         <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

This cleaned pom will use Spring Boot 2.7.5 dependencies (as declared in the parent). If you want to switch to 3.0.0 just change the version of your parent.

**NOTE:** When switching to Spring Boot 3.0.0 you need to use the JakartaEE classes (different packages) instead of the JavaEE packages.